# Printing items in two separate lists in proper alignment using python

Tags: python, printing

I am trying to print items in two separate lists in a way that items in `list-1` will align with items in `list-2`.

Here is my attempt:

```
import numpy as np
list_1=[1,2,3,4]
list_2=np.arange(0.1,0.4,0.1)

for x in list_1:
    j=x/2.0
    for y in list_2:
        print j,',', y
```

My Output:

```
0.5 , 0.1
0.5 , 0.2
0.5 , 0.3
0.5 , 0.4
1.0 , 0.1
1.0 , 0.2
1.0 , 0.3
1.0 , 0.4
1.5 , 0.1
1.5 , 0.2
1.5 , 0.3
1.5 , 0.4
2.0 , 0.1
2.0 , 0.2
2.0 , 0.3
2.0 , 0.4
```

Desired Output:

```
0.5 , 0.1
1.0 , 0.2
1.5 , 0.3
2.0 , 0.4
```

Comment: can you explain what you want a bit better in words. I am almost sure I know what you mean, but a little explanation would help. I am pretty sure you only need one for loop

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for responding. My goal is to print the two lists in such a way that item 1 in list_1 will be in alignment with item 1 in list_2. The desired output in the question is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ok, as I guessed. The answer that was posted should do that for you.

Comment: Range does not work with floating numbers thats why I'm using numpy arange

Comment: `range` is not the answer, `zip` is the answer, you can use `zip` with numpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

**Example:**

```
>>> l1 = range(10)
>>> l2 = range(20,30)
>>> for x,y in zip(l1, l2):
    print x, y

0 20
1 21
2 22
3 23
4 24
5 25
6 26
7 27
8 28
9 29
```

**Explanation:**

`zip` receives iterables, and then iterates over all of them at once, starting from the 0 element of each, then going on to the 1st and then 2nd and so on, once any of the iterables reaches the end - the zip will stop, you can use [`izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) from [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools) to fill empty items in iterables with `None` (or you can do some fancier things - but that is for a different question)

Comment: Thanks @Inbar, zip is actually the answer. I was just wondering if you can zip up to 5 items at a time and sure you can.

Comment: please can you apply the zip function in my actual code to derive the my desired result? Thanks.

Comment: `for x, y in zip(list_1, list_2): print '{}, {}'.format(x/2.0, y)`

Comment: Thanks @Inbar, I just wanted you to put the solution in the actual code before accepting the answer.